# Explain delete_element For loop

Tags: solidity

I'm new to solidity.

Someone please explain "for loop" in solidity and the for loop in the code below.

```
function delete_element(uint index) public returns (bool){
    if(index >= prices.length)
      return false;
  //please explain this for loop
  for (uint i = index; i < prices.length-1 ; i++){
      prices[i] = prices[i+1];
  }
  prices.length--;
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop is deleting an element from an array with shifting all the elements in front of it back one step.
For example let assume the `prices` array is something like this:

```
prices=[250,270,230,400,1000,200]
```

The `delete_element` function gets an uint argument called `index`. Let assume it gets 2 as `index`. In the for loop `uint i = index` is declaring a temporary variable `i` and assigning `index` to it which in our example means `i = 2`.

After `;` you see `i < prices.length-1` this is the ending condition which means this for loop will loop till the the value of `i` is less than `prices.length-1` and as soon as the `i` becomes equal to `prices.length-1` the loop is over. `prices.length` in here is 6 since we have 6 elements in the `prices` array, hence `prices.length-1 = 5` so the loop will end after `i = 4`.

The next code is  `i++` which means increase `i` in the loop by one each time the loop occurs in order to loop the `i` from 2 all the way up to 5.

Inside the for loop we have `prices[i] = prices[i+1];` it means assign the next element to the previous element. In the first loop it'll be like this :

```
prices[2] = prices [3];
```

Inside `prices[2]` we have 250 and inside `prices[3]` is 400. so after this one loop our whole array will loop like this:

```
prices=[250,270,400,400,1000,200];
```

The next loop `i` will increase to 3 so we will have

```
prices[3] = prices [4];
```

Which will change the array to this:

```
prices=[250,270,400,1000,1000,200];
```

and the next loop will change the array to this:

```
prices=[250,270,400,1000,200,200];
```

The next line `prices.length--;` is deleting the last element of array which will make the array to this:

```
prices=[250,270,400,1000,200];
```

now the `prices.length` is 5 instead of 6.

**Be Careful**

This code only works for solidity version `0.5.x` and lower. In new solidity `0.6.x` and higher you can't do this `prices.length--;` . The `length` is now only readable and you can't assign any number to it. in order to delete the last element of an array and decrease the size by 1 you can now use `prices.pop()`

Comment: THIS WAS THE BEST EXPLANATION ✌️✌️ THANK YOU MASOUD JT

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> //please explain this for loop
> for (uint i = index; i < prices.length-1 ; i++){
>     prices[i] = prices[i+1];
> }
> ```

consider `prices = [a, b, c, d, e ,f ,g]` and index is `2` then element to be deleted is `prices[2]` which is `c`. Inside the for loop prices are reassigned to value of the next and deletes the last.

after the for loop ends `prices = [a, b, d, e, f, g, g]` then last element is deleted which gives `[a, b, d ,e, f, g]`. And `c` is not in the list anymore.